# How do I convert the following type of timestamp to seconds since beginning of unix epoch in PHP

Tags: php

I have the following string:

2023-05-10T22:32:21+02:00

I need to convert it to seconds since January 1 1970 00:00:00 GMT (Unix Epoch)

I do not care about the +02:00 section. I just need PHP code to convert the above to a number of seconds. I suppose, I can split the T into 2 strings and then I will have the date and then the time on the right side and then somehow work it out that way but not 100% sure on how to do this.

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat and https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.format.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your date looks to be in the ISO 8601 format.

Make a DateTime Object, with [DateTime::createFromFormat](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php).  With the DateTime object, you can then call the [format method](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.format.php) that has a built in 'U' formating option for Seconds since unix epoch.

> **U**       Seconds since the Unix Epoch (January 1 1970 00:00:00 GMT)

```
<?php

$dt = DateTime::createFromFormat(DateTimeInterface::ISO8601, '2023-05-10T22:32:21+02:00');

echo $dt->format('U');
```

*Result: 1683750741*

You can verify this worked by taking the timestamp value you got, and using the date() function to make a date from the timestamp value, and display it.

```
$dt = DateTime::createFromFormat(DateTimeInterface::ISO8601, '2023-05-10T22:32:21+02:00');

$ts = $dt->format('U');

echo date(DATE_RFC2822, $ts);
```

Result:  ***Wed, 10 May 2023 22:32:21 +0200***